# Invalid number of arguments in ERC20 code?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Im using the official ERC20 code example from here: https://www.ethereum.org/token

I've got everything running fine in truffle, but when i call this function:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }
```

I get `Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function`

I'm running these commands from the truffle console:

```
 var token;
 Token.deployed().then((res) => {token = res});
 var alice = '0xbb452da6021229d93b28a6fea487fd3098eb8b16';
 token.transfer(alice, 44);
```

I've copy pasted the address from the accounts listed by testrpc
Any idea whats going on? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the from:account parameter.

```
var account_one = "0x1234..."; // the address calling this function. Get the list of accounts and use account[0]; 

token.transfer(alice, 44, {from: account_one}).then(function(tx_id) {
  // If this callback is called, the transaction was successfully processed.
  // Note that Ether Pudding takes care of watching the network and triggering
  // this callback.
  alert("Transaction successful!")
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```

Comment: i tried truffle(development)> token.transfer(alice, 55, {from: account_one}); and i got the same error message. I'm really confused since transfer clearly has only two parameters and I'm passing exactly two... (Note that I'm calling transfer not _transfer)

Comment: your code does work though. Can you explain what {from: account_one} is and why it is necessary? Also what is tx_id? Thanks!

Comment: From the Truffle docs: We passed an object as the third parameter to sendCoin. Note that the sendCoin function in our Solidity contract doesn't have a third parameter. What you see above is a special object that can always be passed as the last parameter to a function that lets you edit specific details about the transaction. Here, we set the from address ensuring this transaction came from account_one.

You can use that object to pass, for example, how much gas you want to supply.

tx_id is the id of the transaction returned by this execution.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those that are trying to do without truffle (and with metamask web3 js).

I called this below function on button click for test purpose, and it sent the tokens properly.

*Note : clicking the button will trigger metamask confirmation, submitting which will transfer the tokens upon successful mining into a block.*

```
function transferTokens()
{
    if (typeof web3 == 'undefined') {console.log("Metamask Not found"); return; }
    var contrctAddress = "PLACE_YOUR_CONTRAT_ADDRESS"; //address of token contract
    var abi = []; //REPLACE JSON OF your token contract
    var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    var recipient = "RICIPIENT_ADDRESS"; //to whom you want to send the tokens to
    var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contrctAddress);
    var tokensToSend = 2; //replace with number of tokens to send
    var weiAmount = tokensToSend*1e18;
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
         myContractInstance.transfer(recipient ,weiAmount,function (err, result) {
         if (err) {
              console.log(err); //handle the error
              return;
         }
         else
         {
            console.log('success'); //your code for success
          }
       }); });
}
```